# Iteration to recursion

Tags: java, recursion

```
private int array[][] = new int[5][5];

private void arrayIteration(){
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
            array[i][j] = 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Can I change the iteration method to recursive one that does the same task?

Edit (this is what I've tried but it's just playing with what I want to do):

```
private void arrayRecursion(){
    if(){
        array[i][i] = 10;  // Base
        return;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        arrayRecursion();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could, but why would you?

Comment: Have you tried anything or do you want us to write code for you?

Comment: No, it is not homework. If it was I would have put the proper tag! I guess there should have been a tag called "Not homework". Not everybody here is trying to do their homework.

Comment: @Nath to be fair this is similar to a homework-looking problem, and classes are just starting, so I could see this being a "We want to get a gauge for how well you know some concepts you'll need in this course. Let's see who can do this kind of assignment."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it. Basically you start in the 0,0 corner and set it to the value. Then you do 0,1 and 1,0. 0,1 will set, and do 1,1 and 1,2. 1,0 will set and do 2,0 and 1,1. Note that 1,1 just got hit twice - that's fine because it's overwriting what it did before. When it hits a 'wall' it stops (this means if the [3] array was null, [4] wouldn't get hit) but that isn't a problem for arrays allocated with new `int[x][y]` notation.

```
class Sandbox {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] test = new int[5][5];
        recursiveAssign(test,10);
        int numThatAreTen = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                if(test[i][j] == 10) numThatAreTen++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(numThatAreTen);
    } // main

    static void recursiveAssign(int[][] arr, int value) {
        recursiveAssign0(arr,value,0,0);
    } // recursiveAssign

    static private void recursiveAssign0(int[][] arr, int value, int x, int y) {
        if(arr != null && x < arr.length && arr[x] != null && y < arr[x].length) {
            arr[x][y] = value;
            // now go down, and across
            recursiveAssign0(arr,value,x+1,y);
            recursiveAssign0(arr,value,x,y+1);
        } 
    } // recursiveAssign0

} // Sandbox
```

which prints the expected 25

```
C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>javac Sandbox.java

C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>java Sandbox
25

C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>
```

Comment: And turning a simple seven lines of iterative code into a recursive behemoth like that is _exactly_ why you shouldn't do it :-) I rest my case, your Honour.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can. However, you shouldn't want to. I can write all my applications in assembly code but that doesn't make it a good idea :-)

There are a few algorithms that lend themselves naturally to recursion, those whose operations can be expressed in terms of the same operation on a smaller data set or lesser value (tree traversal, factorials, that sort of thing).

Initialising an array to all zeros is *not* one of those things.

Comment: You can (meaning you have the knowledge and skill to) write all you applications in assembly? :-O

Comment: .. but probably not the time.

Comment: Well, the reason is that somewhere recently I've read that a loop inside a recursive call is basically a nested loop. This is why I was trying to change a nested loop into a recursion call. The example with two dimensional array was the first example that came into my mind that has a nested loop.

Comment: A loop does not incur the stack frame overhead of a recursive call. They are not the same thing.

Comment: @Alxandr it actually doesn't take all that much knowledge and skill to write applications in assembly. I mean you have to memorize all the op-codes, or at least have the ability to look them up, but I don't see this as any different than picking up any other new framework or language. It does take considerable amounts of patience and time, which most people do not have.

Comment: @Nath in addition to Perception's comment about stack overhead, it's worth mentioning that typically, iterative processes are easier to read than recursive ones. Now, this isn't always the case, but in my experience debugging iterative functions is generally easier than debugging iterative ones. Don't get me wrong, plenty of people can debug recursive ones with marginal difficulty, but I would bet that most who can would have an -even easier- time debugging an iterative routine instead.

Comment: @glowcoder I agree with you. But there are problems that can be solved in much more elegant way using recursion rather than using iteration. My favorite example is n-queens problem.

Comment: @Nath Absolutely there are. The key is this isn't really one of them. Now if you're looking exclusively for "I want to train my brain to recognize how to turn iterative processes to recursive ones" then it's not that bad. In fact, a very good exercise in understanding recursion might be to take what I wrote and optimize it to not overlap on spreading. :)